# workflow failed to start due to an internal error

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, error

I have a workflow that is manually started. but when I click on start. it shows an error ' The workflow failed to start due to an internal error. ' . I took the correlation id to know the issue. The error log file says ' Not persisting state for request due to previous errors. Form Template '

Kindly help ASAP ):

Comment: Online or on prem?

Comment: It is prem @MortenK

Comment: Ok if it's 2013 workflow i'd start by checking the workflow manager to see if everything work fine. If that's the case start out by making a simple hello world workflow which just logs something :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while i'm trying to send mails to a group of users through workflow. At that time i have changed my group settings then it works as expected.
[image]